# Google assistant's privacy policiy error is showing in google assistant quiz

Tags: actions-on-google

Google Assistant is showing that my privacy policies are invalid ,while i was creating a quiz in Google Assistant
my privacy poliy document is as follows

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C6G50XX5lOtdjFZTk2Qc9wkSqPKSeaM95Ydw0lt1zGI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your Privacy Policy document is not available to the public. You need to change the permissions on the document so everyone can read it.

Once you've done so, you can test to make sure you can see it without logging in by, for example, testing it with Chrome in Incognito Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the fact that as Prisoner said, your policy needs to be public, also be aware that your policy matches your actions language. I had that mistake so i had to set up a policy for english and one in spanish.